# Hide code from a jsp page if the user who entered is a simple user or is an admin

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

i have a jsp page (login.jsp). what it does is checking the given information and if they are right (they exist in my database) the user enters in the main program. my question is how can i succeeded to "hide" some lines of my code if the user is a "simple" user, and how to not hide if the user is admin.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You could use JSTL `<c:if>`tag in which you put the HTML code you would like to display in case the user is a "simple" user.

Example :

```
<c:if test="${user.isSimple}">
     -> html code here <-
</c:if>
```

Comment: A jsp file is HTML and jsp tags, I don't see the issue here.

Comment: thnx! i will check it again!

Comment: So 1) check the user exists in your DB ; 2) if it exists, determine whether it's a simple user or an admin ; 3) Store somehow this information (either as a variable in your session or as a field in a User class model) ; 4) Use this field as a condition in a if statement and put the specific HTML code within.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable in your session that shows if this user is admin or not, it could be a field in your user model, and in your `JSP` file, you can [`<c:if>`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_if_tag.htm) tag to show this specific admin part

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>

<c:if test = "${isAdminUser}">
     <p>Only visible for admin<p>
</c:if>
```

Comment: i have allready done that but if i put your code in my jsp file i get a NullPointerException from glassfish

Comment: @fotis You should define the variable `isAdminUser` in your session, or you can use any field in your user model that describe if the user is admin or not

Comment: ok i got it! thnx! i will contact you if a have problem! thnx for your time

Comment: @fotis Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.